# How to integrate over a random variable to get the expectancy value

Tags: stochastic-integrals, expected-value

We examine stochastic in math and got to expected values variances. I don't understand the definition of expected values. The following picture is in German.

[image: Picture]

It says: Is $X \in L^1(\Omega, \mathfrak{U}, P) $ an integrable random variable, then 
$$
E[X] = \int X d P
$$

is the expectancy value of X.

I have no idea how to read this. How do you integrate over a random Variable X with P?

P is of course a probability measure.

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Definition) for the definition of a random variable. It is a measurable function. In your example it is even $L^1$ to make sure its integral (i.e. its expectation) is well defined.

Comment: Good question.  This is an advanced measure-theory definition of expectation. It is not helpful if you don't know what that kind of integral is. If $X$ is a nonnegative random variable then an equivalent definition is $$ E[X] = \int_{0}^{\infty} P[X>x]dx$$ More basic (and less general) definitions are: (i) If $X$ has PDF $f_X(x)$ then $$E[X] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xf_X(x)dx$$ whenever the integral makes sense (gives finite value), (ii) If $X$ takes values on a discrete set $\mathcal{X}$ then $$E[X] = \sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}} xP[X=x]$$ whenever the sum makes sense (gives finite value).